# How to globally add exception handler configuration to server block under /etc/nginx/sites-available?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I want to apply a solution for 403 forbidden default error. I have 100s of sites under /etc/nginx/sites-available. I created a 403.html file (/usr/share/nginx/html) and added the following code in the */etc/nginx/snippets/custom_exception.conf *

```
    error_page 403 /403.html;

    location = /403.html {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
```

I tested this code for one site by adding the following line

`include /etc/nginx/snippets/custom_exception.conf;`

It's working fine. The code should be in the server block of every file. Issue is I am not convinced to make this change for each and every file in the production server.

I have tried couple of ways in the nginx.conf file as follows, yet not working

```
http {
...
 
 include /etc/nginx/snippets/custom_exception.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

```
http {
...
 server {
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/custom_exception.conf;
 }

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`error_page` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) *can* be placed in `http` context.

Unfortunately, the [`location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) (or the include file that contains it) **must** be copied into **every** relevant `server` block.

At least, if you edit every `server` block to add an `include` statement - you will only ever need to do it the one time.

---

Alternatively, if this works for you and your clients, you put the 403.html page into a separate domain and specify the full URL in the `error_page` statement. This removes the requirement to edit every `server` block.

For example:

```
error_page 403      http://example.com/forbidden.html;
```